# Youtube Notifications on 3rd party app

Tags: php, android, youtube-api

I have an android app that fetches the video from the YouTube channel. It is working fine. The problem is, I want to send the notifications to all the users who have installed the app, even if they are not subscribed to the YouTube. Videos list is fetched from PHP API at my server.

1. I am thinking of calling the cron every 5 minutes, which I think not a good logic.
2. Is there any kind of YouTube API or settings that, we can use so as that my server API can be called and I can send the notifications from server itself.

**NOTE**:-

Notifications will be sent of every channel video add, update or delete functionality.

Answer (score 1):

As for the API itself, I am not an expert so it is not my place to advise, however on the cron you could run it every second in reality as long as you server has the power to deal with the load.

Comment: but if channel has 1000 of videos, then my server will be overloaded. and i will be required to check each and every video.

Comment: You may have to look at "outsourcing" a server then, one with more power and higher capabilities, as you have stated you will need to be able to run the cron as much as possible to reduce the load put on you, so to have a server that cannot deal with this workload is a massive issue, I really would suggest looking to use an external server (or multiple) that allow you to run a lot of cron's at once